# Roslyn: Auto generating methods from controller routes

Tags: code-generation, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I wrote a [Roslyn source generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) that visits all of my controllers' methods that have an HttpGet, HttpPut, HttpDelete or HttpPost attribute on them, and then makes classes like this, that I was hoping to make available to my Blazor client classes:

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by OurGov.Data.Shared.Generators.ApiRoutesGenerator version 1.0.4.1
// </auto-generated>


#nullable enable

namespace OurGov.Data.Shared.Models.Routes;

/// <summary>Defines routes.</summary>
public static partial class ApiRoutes
{
    /// <summary>Endpoints for EventsController</summary>
    public static class EventsRoutes
    {
        /// <summary>HttpGet: See EventsController.GetEventsForFeed</summary>
        public static string GetEventsForFeed(string filterValue) => $"api/events/feed/{filterValue}";


        ...more endpoints...
        
        /// <summary>HttpPost: See EventsController.GetHearingsForCommittee</summary>
        public static string GetHearingsForCommittee() => $"api/events/hearings/search";
    }
}
```

I set the namespace to be the same namespace as *if* it were a part of the OurGov.Data.Shared .DLL, but, alas, (and in retrospect, obviously) this does not make it so.

How would I go about generating code from my startup project (i.e. where my controllers are) and then having those newly generated classes automatically (ideally) be consumable by downstream projects (projects that the Server has a dependency on)?

Here's an image depicting the architecture:
[image: Architecture of project dependencies.]

Answer (score 1):

Incremental source generators are prohibited from accessing files outside the project they're targeting. They also can't make network calls and can't easily use NuGet packages. All of these things can be done with an old fashioned console app source generator. I haven't used one of these in a while and don't know how well they're working in recent versions of .NET and Visual Studio.

There isn't a definitive source I can point you to about how to write console app source generators. If you go this route, you'll have to piece it together from old blog posts. Here's an example that I wrote a few years ago: [NSwagClientGenerator](https://github.com/kjkrum/NSwagClientGenerator).